# NodeJS Headers - adding slashes when posted?

Tags: node.js, https, http-headers

I'm experiencing a strange problem when using native nodejs to post a header to a third party end point. Since i've got no control over this end point it's been hard to debug.

I'm passing a custom header called token. This value can contain forward slashes.

If it does contain slashes I can see that the response from the remote end point has a backward slash to escape it. If I pass in a token without a slash it works fine.

**Fail example:**

Nodejs
token: "/test/token/with/slashes"

API Response
`{result:"fail", token: "\/test\/token\/with\/slashes"}`

**Pass example:**

Nodejs
token: "1234"

API Response
{result:"ok", token: "1234"}

The problem is the token will always have a slash. I've tried using postman to replicate the call with a token that contain slashes and it works fine. Therefore i'm assuming node js is adding these prior to the request being made?

Any insight on how to get around this would be much appreciated.

```js
var post_data = querystring.stringify({
    "value1" : "some value",
    "value": "some value 2"
});

var post_options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "hostname": "mydomain.com",
  "port": null,
  "path": "/REST/api/some-end-point",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data;",
    "token": "/YdIbwH6WAH/Djdw4JFH9/",
  }
};

var post_req = https.request(post_options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding("utf8");
  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      console.log("Response: " + chunk);
      var parsed = JSON.parse(chunk);
      console.log(parsed)
  });
});
// post the data
post_req.write(post_data);
post_req.end();
```

Comment: I'm using Node 6 version hosted on AWS Lamda.
I've also tried using the generated code from postman for node js native, the result is sadly the same.

Comment: Hey TechyAdam, could you try escaping the token before you send it to third party endpoint.  Postman is a different client, and we dont know how inputs are dealt within that client. So just try adding backslashes to the forward slashes in token

Comment: To escape the token you could try something like: -      token.replace('/','/\//');

Comment: @Aditya Sadly tried that but still no luck: Response came back with:

`7MO1kvXZETObsl\/\/\/XY4wosoJVlr0UzeY`

Comment: What was the request you sent and actual complete response you received. If you can share, It will give me some insight.

Comment: @Aditya Here's some data:

https://pastebin.com/usp9CLt9

Comment: Apologies for asking lot many questions, but can you also post the request and response without using token.replace. In that case just comment the replace token statement.

Comment: @Aditya certainly! - this is without token replace, it doesn't even get detected from the response. https://pastebin.com/n4DSQSLR I've tried wrapping it in double quotes, it get's returned but the quotes are then escaped :S - thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139148/discussion-between-techyadam-and-aditya).